How to connect Azure web app (App Service) to an Azure SQL database
I'm trying to connect an ASP.NET project that's deployed in Azure as an App Service to an Azure SQL database.
But it can't reach the database, even though I've tried to match the connection strings.

could you please provide your approach and error if got any?

For just instance, im trying to access one of the endpoints which would just take the users from the DB and return them as a list. Im trying to test it with postman. Locally, it works, and the other API-s work as well, only those dont that needs access to the database

provide the error which you are getting?

HTTP500: 500 Internal Server Error
The server has encountered a situation it does not know how to handle.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have not supplied any code so we cannot recreate the problem. Have you opened the firewall on your database server to allow access from your app? Assuming this is for testing/POC purposes you will need allow access from all azure services. If this is for a project you should be looking at using vnets and private endpoints to secure access between the 2.


How to connect Azure web app (App Service) to an Azure SQL database

The reason for the HTTP 500 Internal Server Error can be due to multiple reasons, such as code issues, database connection issues, and incorrect configuration. Make sure to check the connection string, permissions, and networking configuration.
I agree with Anupam Chand for suggesting the same point.
To establish a connection from the App Service to the SQL database, you can follow the steps below.
Method: 1 Public
If you want to connect via a public network, make sure to enable it for all networks on both resources, so that the App Service can connect to the SQL Database.
Method 2: Vnet

If you are trying to connect via a VNet, create a subnet and add the  Microsoft.Sql  delegation. The App Service will communicate with the SQL database through the Microsoft Backbone Network without exposing it to the public.



Allow the VNet in the Azure SQL Database firewall settings to permit traffic from the App Service.


Reference: Grant access from a virtual network
Azure NAT Gateway integration
Stack link for the same related issue

Yeah, i've tried this one as well, but even after this, it didn't work. since then, i was able to make it work, by adding read and write rights to the desired component by it's name in the database's query option

Read and write operations require permission, as stated earlier. The 500 error occurs for various reasons.
